# Access point and working DNS

Tags: kali-linux, dns, access-point

I want to organize an access point in `Kali Linux OS`.

I do it with the command tool:  `sudo berate_ap -n wlan0 Testing 12345678`.
The access point is working well. A new interface appears in the network settings: `ap0`.
Clients also successfully connect to this access point and receive the following network settings:

`IP: 192.168.12.*/24`
`Gateway: 192.168.12.1`
`DNS: 192.168.12.1`

My task is as follows: so that the laptop on which this access point is accessible from the phone (i.e. from the client device that is connected to this dsoup point) `by domain name`, i.e. so that from the phone I typed into the browser, `for example, testing.net`, I got to this laptop, or rather, to the service that is spinning there, I can log in by IP, but I can’t by the domain name.

Could you tell me please, how can I implement such a task?

I tried to do something through the `bind9` utility, but nothing worked for me. too complicated setup and it is not clear what's what.
Maybe there is a faster and easier way.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just skip the `bind9` part. Set the DNS as 1.1.1.1 (or better: the external DNS you are using).

Comment: Do you mean that on the laptop and on the client to specify DNS type 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 or 1.1.1.1?

Comment: instead of `DNS: 192.168.12.1`. I do not know `berate_ap`, but from your post, it seems it does some DHCP part (which it is essential to let user to connect to WiFi). So you change the configuration

Comment: unfortunately, nothing works.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help and participation, I solved this issue in another query. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/737336/453555