# Add another name to DNS server bind9

Tags: kali-linux, dns, bind, bind9

I set up a `DNS server` using the `bind9` utility, took the `settings` from the example, and this is how the `configuration` turned out:

file: `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone    "testing.net" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.forward.com";
};

zone    "12.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.reverse.com";
};
```

file: `/etc/bind/db.forward.com`

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.testing.net. root.localhost. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.testing.net.
ns      IN      A       192.168.12.1
server  IN      A       192.168.12.1
www     3600    IN      CNAME ns.testing.net.
```

file: `/etc/bind/db.reverse.com`

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.testing.net. root.localhost. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.
1       IN      PTR     ns.testing.net.
1       IN      PTR     ns.testing.net.
```

I have a service running on the system which is available by the name `demo.testing.net`.
I also implement an access point on this system, clients connected to it can access the name `ns.testing.net`.

Could you tell me please, how do I set up a config in `bind9` so that clients can access the system called `demo.testing.net`? What should be `specified` in the `configuration files`?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Linux hosts you should put the following in their /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 192.168.12.1
search testing.net
```

They should then test with:

```
ping demo
```

Don't forget to put the following line in /etc/bind/db.forward.com:

```
demo  IN      A       192.168.12.<host ip>
```

and in /etc/bind/db.reverse.com:

```
<host ip>     IN      PTR     demo.testing.net.
```

and restart your bind9 server.

Good luck.